# How to correctly remove a PPA source?

Tags: ppa, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

If I've added a PPA with "sudo add-apt-repository" should I just delete a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d, or there is a command for removal?